# Content Search KQL fields

Tags: web-part, search, content, web

I'm setting up a content search to find tasks assigned to users and was wondering where SP came up with fields like StatusOWSCHCS, what does the OWSCHCS stand for or OWSNMBR - I'm assuming this OWS number!? Then what is OWS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During a crawl, a crawled property is automatically created for the site column. Say for example we have 2 site columns (Color and weight). The name of this property is generated by removing spaces from the site column name, and adding a prefix. The prefix that is added varies depending on the site column type.
For example, we get the following crawled properties:

**ows**_q_TEXT_Color

**ows**_q_NMBR_Weight

A managed property is then automatically created, which is mapped to the corresponding crawled property. The name of this property is generated by removing spaces from the site column name, and adding a suffix. The suffix that is added varies depending on the site column type. 
So, in this example, we get the following managed properties:

Color**OWS**TEXT
Weight**OWS**NMBR

The task status column is actually a site column so its managed property will be STATUSOWSCHCS

For more info: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj613136.aspx